# Excel: How do I return an array of values based off of duplicates in a corresponding column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e8E0.png]

Based off of Column 1, is there an excel formula I could write in Column 3 that groups True/False (in Column 2) by duplicate letters and identifies if these letter groups contain at least one True.

Ex: Group A = {True, False, True, False} --> Contains at least one True and thus all 4 rows with Letter A have True in Column 3

*Rows in Column 1 aren't necessarily alphabetized and are listed without any particular order.

I have tried using match/index excel functions and I seem to be having trouble since match only returns the position of the first match.

I understand once I have this array of boolean values, "OR" can be used to determine Column 3 simply.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,TRUE)>0
```

[image]

Comment: Oh great! This is a lot simpler than what I was trying to attempt. Thank you for your help.